# glReadPixels does not work in WebRTC Android SurfaceViewRenderer

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview

I'm trying to save frame from WebRTC Android appication. In [SurfaceViewRenderer.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/branch-heads/48/talk/app/webrtc/java/android/org/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer.java) it draws YUV frame using GLES shader. To save the drawn frame I added saveFrame() from [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java) to SurfaceViewRenderer.java but when I call saveFrame() it doesn't work(the bitmap is empty). I thought glReadPixels() read pixels from current color buffer but it seems it wasn't called in current EGLcontext? How to call glReadPixels() to save current frame?

the codes what I wrote are like this:

In MainActivity I added button like this.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bitmap = localSurfaceViewRender.saveFrame();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    });
```

In SurfaceViewRenderer.java I added some methods to get values from currently binded egl

```
public int getSurfaceHeight() {
    if (mHeight < 0) {
        return eglBase.surfaceHeight();
    } else {
        return mHeight;
    }
}

public int getSurfaceWidth() {
    if (mWidth < 0) {
        return eglBase.surfaceWidth();
    } else {
        return mWidth;
    }
}


public Bitmap saveFrame() {
    int width = eglBase.surfaceWidth();
    int height = eglBase.surfaceHeight();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    GLES20.glFinish();
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
    GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error("glReadPixels");
    buf.rewind();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);
    return bmp;
}
```

**Edit:**
This code is the full code of saveFrame

```
// save as a file
        public void saveFrame(final File file) {
            runOnRenderThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int width = eglBase.surfaceWidth();
                    int height = eglBase.surfaceHeight();
                    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4);
                    buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
                    GLES20.glFinish();
                    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
                    GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error("glReadPixels");
                    buf.rewind();

                    // fliping by vertical
                    byte[] tmp = new byte[width * 4];
                    for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; i++) {
                        buf.get(tmp);
                        System.arraycopy(buf.array(), buf.limit() - buf.position(),
                                buf.array(), buf.position() - width * 4, width * 4);
                        System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, buf.array(), buf.limit() - buf.position(), width * 4);
                    }
                    buf.rewind();

                    String filename = file.toString();
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                    try {
                        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);
                        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                        bmp.recycle();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (bos != null) try {
                            bos.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "Saved " + width + "x" + height + " frame as '" + filename + "'");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glReadPixels()` function reads the contents of a framebuffer from the current context.  Once `eglSwapBuffers()` is called, the contents are gone.

Put another way, apps can't read anything out of a SurfaceView.  So you have to read the pixels out just before you submit the buffer to the compositor.

(I'm not actually sure what happens if you call `glReadPixels()` right after swapping buffers... it's possible you'll read a previously-sent frame from a recycled buffer, but you can't always rely on that.)

You appear to be calling `glReadPixels()` from the main UI thread.  If the SurfaceView rendering is occurring on a different thread, you would need to access the framebuffer from that same thread, because that's where the EGL context is current.  A given context can't be current in more than one thread at a time.

Comment: Thanks fadden. There is a runOnRenderThread method in SurfaceViewRenderer.java. I called saveframe() inside of this method then It works fine.

Comment: @kju for me calling saveframe() on runOnRenderThread method returns black image. Please help in this how you have done this. Thanks

Comment: Hey @kju how to make this saving bitmaps asynchronous so it wont make UI freeze. anything else we need to do? i tried few things like asynctask n all it seems not to be working!